# Einstein notation - difference between vectors and scalars

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, tensors

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation):

> First, we can use Einstein notation in
>   linear algebra to distinguish easily
>   between vectors and covectors: upper
>   indices are used to label components 
>   (coordinates) of vectors, while lower
>   indices are used to label components
>   of covectors. However, vectors
>   themselves (not their components) have
>   lower indices, and covectors have
>   upper indices.

I am trying to read the Wikipedia article, but I am constantly getting confused between what represents a vector/covector and what represents a component of one of these. How can I tell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A vector component is always written with 1 upper index $a^i$, while a covector component is written with 1 lower index $a_i$.

In Einstein notation, if the same index variable appear in both upper and lower positions, an implicit summation is applied, i.e.

$$ a_i b^i = a_1 b^1 + a_2 b^2 + \dotsb \qquad (*) $$

Now, a vector is constructed from its component as

$$ \mathbf a = a^1 \mathbf{\hat e}_1 + a^2 \mathbf{\hat e}_2 + \dotsb $$

where $\mathbf{\hat e}_i$ are the basis vectors. But this takes the form like (*), so if we make basis vectors to take lower indices, we will get

$$ \mathbf a = a^i \mathbf{\hat e}_i $$

This is likely what Wikipedia means.

Comment: Okay, so $a_i b^i$ doesn't represent the product of a vector times a covector, but a sum over elements. That confused me

Comment: @Casebash: Right, $a_i b^i$ as a dot product is just a special case. For instance, we could use $x_i{}^i$ to represent the trace of a 2-tensor.